# How to pass mutiple city id in sql query

Tags: sql

My sql query as follows

```
select DISTINCT date_TripDate AS TripDate,
                traveltype.varchar_TravelTypeCode AS TripType,
                contactss.Value as Mobilenumber,
from [OneC_988].[dbo].[988_Details_VehicleRequest] request
join [OneC_988].[dbo].[988_Details_VehicleTrip] trip
    on  request.int_VehicleRequestID = trip.int_VehicleRequestID
    and int_CityID ='1'
```

When I run the above query output as follows

Tripdate TripType Mobilenumber int_CityID

```
26th aug 16 IN 9878778878 1
26th aug 16 IN 9949949990 1
26th aug 16 IN 9878778878 1
```

I want to pass both INT_CityID 1 and 2 in the above sql query to get output as follows

Tripdate TripType Mobilenumber int_CityID

```
26th aug 16 IN 9878778878 1
26th aug 16 IN 9949949990 1
26th aug 16 IN 9878778878 1

28th aug 16 IN 9878778878 2
28th aug 16 IN 9949949990 2
28th aug 16 IN 9878778878 2
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, though valid question but in this case how does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

Use IN clauese like the below script ..

```
select DISTINCT date_TripDate AS TripDate,traveltype.varchar_TravelTypeCode AS TripType,contactss.Value as Mobilenumber,from [OneC_988].[dbo].[988_Details_VehicleRequest] request join [OneC_988].[dbo].[988_Details_VehicleTrip] trip on request.int_VehicleRequestID=trip.int_VehicleRequestID
    and int_CityID  IN ('1','2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT 
    date_TripDate AS TripDate,
    traveltype.varchar_TravelTypeCode AS TripType,
    contactss.Value as Mobilenumber,
from 
    [OneC_988].[dbo].[988_Details_VehicleRequest] request 
join 
    [OneC_988].[dbo].[988_Details_VehicleTrip] trip 
on 
    request.int_VehicleRequestID=trip.int_VehicleRequestID
and 
    (int_CityID ='1' OR int_CityID ='2')
```

You can use OR in a JOIN condition. You could also use UNION, that may execute faster.